# BusyBox tee is very slow

Tags: bash, pipe, busybox, tee, process-substitution

I am using Puppy-4.3.1 Linux on some older (Pentium 4) hardware.

I am getting terrible performance out of the `tee` command.

On this distro, `tee` is part of `BusyBox v1.15.0`.

For example, this command without `tee` takes **0.05** seconds to execute.

```
cat "$my1megfile" | sha256sum
```

By contrast, if I use a `tee` with process substitution, it takes **15.36** seconds to complete, **307** times longer!

```
cat "$my1megfile" | tee >(sha256sum) >/dev/null
```

Is there something wrong with this `BusyBox` build, or am I doing something wrong?

Can I implement my own `tee` in Bash?

I need to pipe a command (binary) output to two other commands, one of them being `sha256sum`.

Comment: How long does `cat "$my1megfile" | tee /dev/null | sha256sum` take? Maybe it's not about `tee`; maybe it's about the process substitution. `cat` is useless here but I kept it in order not to deviate from what you have already measured. How do you measure exactly?

Comment: @Kamil: 15.04 seconds. I measured with `time` and manually. `cat` is only there to generate stdout for testing purposes.

Comment: On Puppy, I found awk was quicker than many of the busybox utilities (e.g. `awk 'END { print NR; }'` 20 times faster than `wc -l`. Try tee as `awk '{ print; print | "sha256sum"; }'` for comparison.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant: Using your `awk` command works well with text streams. Execution time is **0.25** seconds for the example above. Unfortunately this does not work with binary streams - it produces a wrong checksum. Try the example using a binary file.

Comment: Awk will split a binary file at any 0x0A (newline) bytes, but replace them at the print statement. But will also add newline on an incomplete last line. This can be avoided in GNU/awk like `awk -v RS="^$" '{ printf ("%s", $0) }'`, but that would read the whole file into memory, and may not work on your distro. With timings of 0.05 versus 15.35, your best workaround may be to read the file twice -- it will be cached by the first read anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest **busybox-1.32**, the **FEATURE_TEE_USE_BLOCK_IO** configuration parameter to optimize the performances of the `tee` applet is set to **"yes"** by default:

> config FEATURE_TEE_USE_BLOCK_IO
> bool "Enable block I/O (larger/faster) instead of byte I/O"
> default y
> depends on TEE
> help
> Enable this option for a faster tee, at expense of size.

In **busybox-1.15**, the same parameter is set to **"no"** by default. This may explain why `tee` is slow on your system running **busybox-1.15**.

### For more details:

When **FEATURE_TEE_USE_BLOCK_IO** is **not set**, `tee` does a char by char copy of its input (with *getchar()*) to its outputs (with *putc()*):

```c
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        fp = files;
        do
            putc(c, *fp++);
        while (*fp);
    }
```

When **FEATURE_TEE_USE_BLOCK_IO** is **set**, `tee` uses a buffered copy instead:

```c
    while ((c = safe_read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
        fp = files;
        do
            fwrite(buf, 1, c, *fp++);
        while (*fp);
    }
```

Comment: Can we set it to *yes* from command line, or do we have to rebuild the `busybox`?

Comment: A rebuild is necessary.